# Django site not updating files immediately with Filezilla but fine with putty/nano?

Tags: python, django

I have spent 18 hours trying to find an answer to this, and so I hope my question is ok.

I have set up shared hosting on A Small Orange, and have installed django using a virtual environment.

I'm following a tutorial playing with formatting. When I update a .py file that controls the format of the page (the file is admin.py within the /home/user/website/myproject/myapp folder) it doesn't update on the site immediately.

I've been back and forth with tech support and so far have:

1. Disabled nginx (or as much as possible)
2. Stopped browser caching
3. Stopped storing py file as pyc files
4. Set my django cache setting to dummy cache as per the docs

I've noticed that if I update files using Filezilla - they dont update for 15-30 minutes (even though the updated file is shown correctly in filezilla). If i use Putty to get a command line, and then update a file using nano, it updates instantly...

Why is it only ftp that experiences a delay?

Comment: typically I have to restart my server if I'm making changes to the admin, models etc... 

If your hosting provider is scanning your files via some filescan before they become available, well then I would probably find another host because that would be awful.